# Encrypt both mail body and attachment with gnus

Tags: gnus, gpg, attachment

I'd like to encrypt with gpg some mail messages sent with gnus. When there is no attachment, epa-mail-encrypt works and I get a gpg-encrypted mail message. However, if I add an attachment and then run epa-mail-encrypt, no attachment is sent, and the email received only has the

```
<#part type="application/pdf" filename="some-file.pdf" disposition=attachment>
<#/part>
```

mime part designation encrypted in the body.

I'm looking for a gnus addon that would extend epa-mail-encrypt in order to encrypt all mime parts of the message (body, pdf attachments...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out

```
C-c RET C p:    mml-secure-encrypt-pgpmime
```

is the right tool for that.